# MySql- When should I use lock

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a users table with `gifts_count` and `user_id` fields

Should I add lock to the next statement(it may come from many threads)?

```
update users set gifts_count = gifts_count + 1 where users.user_id = user_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html) rather than explicit table locking.

An example session would look something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE `users` SET `gifts_count` = `gifts_count` + 1 WHERE `users`.`user_id` = user_id;
COMMIT;
```

You can also do some integrity checks if you needed to (depending on what you're doing), between the query and the `COMMIT`, if something goes wrong, you can always use `ROLLBACK`.

---

If you want to prevent reads on the specific row when it's updated (if using `InnoDB` with row-level locking), you can run your `SELECT` query with `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` at the end, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` `users`.`user_id` = user_id LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

That query will hang until your transaction is `COMMIT`ed or `ROLLBACK`'d.

Comment: When I use transaction will my gifts_count be accessible for reading?

Comment: @Babibu They are. I guess if you didn't want this to be possible you *should* use locking (ie. a row-level read lock) ;) **EDIT**: Actually, I'm not even sure anymore, haven't used this in a while, let me check.